# List connected Bluetooth LE devices to Windows 8 with python

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to be able to read out information about connected Bluetooth Low Energy HID devices in Windows 8. My main application uses Qt, but I thought it could be much easier to get help from a Python script. Since Windows 8.1 supports Bluetooth Low Energy natively, I connect my mouse to it and tried using the [pywinusb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinusb/) package, but it doesn't seem to be able to read out this wirelessly connected device, only connected HID devices.

How can I read out information about my BLE device with Python?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a BLE question, but more of a USB question.  Is there a py library for using the Win 8 BLE drivers?  Usually you can get a list of BLE devices through that.

Comment: @TimTisdall It is not a USB question since there are no USB involved. If you find a library, well that would most possibly be a good answer to my question.

Comment: sorry.  I saw "pywinusb" and assumed you were trying to detect the wireless device via USB.  I see from the docs it does a little more.  However, you'll want to detect using a BLE library as it's possible to connect non-HID devices (perhaps even your mouse) that pywinusb wouldn't see.  Unfortunately all my experience is with Linux and I can't help direct you with that.